# What glue should I use with acrylic and transparencies?

Tags: adhesives, acrylic-glass, transparency

I have a set of laser-cut clear acrylic pieces and matching transparencies (with designs printed on them). I want to glue the transparencies atop the acrylic pieces, but I am unsure which glue is suitable for this job. I (naively) used superglue at first, but soon learned that it leaves foggy residue and splotchy remnants of the glue. What type of glue should I use to bond the acrylic and transparencies together that will dry clear and leave little to no residue? If possible, I would prefer an affordable solution that dries quickly.

Comment: At worst, I think, neatly cut and positioned small squares of clear double-sided scotch tape could do the job (near the corners of the transparencies). Even if not attention-grabbing, they would remain somewhat visible though.

Comment: When you say transparencies, do you mean polyester (often called acetate but it isn't any more) sheets as would be used for overhead projectors?  Different plastics require different glues.

Comment: Yes, I am using the overhead projector transparencies.

Answer (score 5):

There are specific [glues](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0149IG548) manufactured for gluing clear and colored acrylic. It is thinner than water and will spread via capillary action when used appropriately. Consider when locating and purchasing such an adhesive to also purchase the needle-tipped dispensers often offered during the transaction.

[image: acrylic cement and applicator]

image courtesy of linked Amazon source.

Ensure that your parts are solidly joined and carefully tip the applicator while the end of the applicator is in contact with the joint. You'll be able to see the glue spread throughout the length of the joined pieces.

Due to the very fast curing time, any excessive quantity that spreads to a surface will damage the surface if removal is attempted. Consider to practice on scrap or test joints to get a feel for the process.

If you intend to layer the acrylic, the same process applies, as the glue will wick into the entire surface contact points/area.

Drying time can often be measured in single-digit seconds.

Comment: Do you know how well that work given the dissimilar plastics? It may vary with brand as some solvent cements use toluene and others dichloromethane to partially dissolve the acrylic.  Transparencies are apparently polyester; you don't want them to dissolve completely, and you may or may not want some service dissolution.  The print is likely to be attacked if any solvent gets on it, even small amounts at the edges.  It sounds worth a try on scrap/cheap material, buying minimal quantities of solvent